# How is earthquake shapeable?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, area-of-effect

The [earthquake](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/earthquake.html) spell has a 80-ft.-radius spread (S) which means it is [shapeable](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#x-s-shapeable). What does that actually mean if it is an 80-ft.-radius the shape seems pre-determined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is still shapeable, even if the area of effect isn't defined in cubes. Cubes are only *sometimes* used, to make it more convenient, but spells without areas defined by cubes are still shapeable if they're marked as [shapeable](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#aiming-a-spell):

> (S) Shapeable: If an area or effect entry ends with "(S)," you can shape the spell. A shaped effect or area can have no dimension smaller than 10 feet. **Many effects or areas are given as cubes to make it easy to model irregular shapes.**

“Many,” but not all! *Earthquake* is one of those exceptions.

An area defined as a (spherical) spread gives the volume available to shape. You just have to use geometry skills and equations to figure out the volume you have available to work with, and the size of the legal reshapings you could choose. ([Or leverage WolframAlpha, I guess!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume%20of%20an%2080%20foot%20sphere))

In practical terms, this means that, among other shapes, you could make a long, narrow *earthquake* (a cylinder of diameter 10 feet, up to [27,307 feet long](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cylinder+length,+10+foot+diameter,+2.14466%C3%9710%5E6+ft%5E3+volume) or [spell range] distance from you, [whichever is closer](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#range)) rip open a crack in the ground and do other earthquake-y things in that narrow tube.

**Wait! Why so big?** Because shapeable does *not* limit you to the original dimensions of the area of effect — shapeable lets you rearrange its cubic feet however you like. The printed area of effect is what you start with, and provides a volume limit — it doesn't limit you to only play “inside” that original shape.

However, despite that lack of dimension limit from the area of effect line, there still is an upper limit on how far away you can make any part of your modified area of effect though:

> ### [Range](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#range)
>
> […] A spell's range is the **maximum distance from you that the spell's effect can occur**, as well as the maximum distance at which you can designate the spell's point of origin. **If any portion of the spell's area would extend beyond this range, that area is wasted**.

So although you can make a 10-foot diameter tube of *earthquake* goodness that is theoretically 27,307 feet long, in *practice* you're limited by the 400 feet + 40 feet/level range of *earthquake*, so even a 20th-level druid could only make that 10-foot diameter tube a maximum of 1200 feet long if it was centered on herself.

Comment: A cylinder and a sphere are two very different shapes. Also, the spell description does not state that the area is a sphere. I am pretty sure the area is 2-dimensional for Earthquake since, to my knowledge, all 3-dimensional spells specifically state that they are 3-dimensional.

Comment: @GreedyRadish Spreads are spherical unless the spell explicitly says otherwise, and *earthquake* doesn't. (I expected it to be circular too, but it turns out not to be.) And “shapeable” means you can arrange its cubic feet volume in any way you want, provided no dimension is less than 10 feet. That includes cylinders, snakes, stars, donuts, [giant people drawings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazca_Lines#/media/File:L%C3%ADneas_de_Nazca,_Nazca,_Perú,_2015-07-29,_DD_46.JPG), etc. The only limitation is range, which defines the maximum extent of any area of effect (including shapeable ones).

Comment: @Trisped the entire point of a shapeable spell is that you can change the shape of it.

Comment: @Trisped See the bold line in my first quote. Being defined in cubes is not required to be able to make it any new irregular shape you want — being defined in cubes is only for convenience, to make irregular shape calculations easy. A *shapeable* volume is just that — shapeable however you like.

Comment: @Trisped I seems to have initially misunderstood your “one dimensional” comment. Regardless, I firmly disagree: shapeable doesn't say that only the radius can be altered, it literally says that the whole shape can be changed to whatever you want. You just can't exceed the defined cubic foot volume.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie While your interpretation creates situations that are a nightmare for any GM to deal with, it does seem to be the correct interpretation assuming that the area of the spell is 3-dimensional and not 2-dimensional.

Comment: @GreedyRadish High level magic does tend to cause headaches, doesn't it?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Do you have references for that?  It makes sense and follows D&D rules I have read, but the current quotes in your answer do not cover any of that.  Is there something which defines what it means to shape a spell?  (Google has failed me).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It certainly does. Now I am imagining one of my players asking "How far down is the core of the planet?"

Comment: @Trisped The quotes look like they cover it fully to me.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: "Spreads are spherical unless the spell explicitly says otherwise, and earthquake doesn't". Good grief, so "things clearly stated to be areas are nevertheless volumes unless specifically stated to not be volumes"? Bad Pathfinder, no doughnut. This may be a bug rather than a feature. On open ground there's very rarely a benefit to using earthquake with more than its minimum height, since it only affects the ground. Anyone who learns it should pre-calculate the equivalent circular effect that they're *actually* going to use, which is 261 feet radius by 10 feet high :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop That it inherits from D&D 3.x, word-for-word!

Comment: Our table simply interpreted the shapeable spell's radius as the 'effect limit' - as in, shape is as you like, as long as the shape is *completely contained* within a 80 ft. sphere. This is much more limited than the 'use 2,144,660 cubed feet any way you like' - but much more manageable. I'm not sure why bother mentioning the 80 ft. radius in the first place if RAI was use 2 million cubic feet...

Comment: @G0BLiN Seems obvious to me that it's because a 80 ft. radius is a succinct description of a volume, and because of the first quote in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you can reshape the volume of the spell to any contiguous volume, with a minimum dimension of 10', so long as the volume remains inside the range of the spell. You can even put holes in it to exempt yourself and your allies.

[Shapeable](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#x-s-shapeable) areas

> ... can have no dimension smaller than 10 feet. Many effects or areas are given as cubes to make it easy to model irregular shapes. Three-dimensional volumes are most often needed to define aerial or underwater effects and areas.

So for an 80' [spread](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#burst-emanation-or-spread) the volume could be broken up into 10' cubes for easy shaping, making
   \$((4/3)\pi\times 80^3)/1000\$ of them, or about 2144 10' cubes. (That's a lot!)
The range is \$ 400'+40'\times CL\$, presuming 15th level, that's 1000', and 1200' at 20th level. Just keep them contiguous.

- Remember that the range is centered on the caster, so that 1000 to 1200' range can be a total length of up to 2400', if you extend it in opposing directions from the caster's position. It could be 80' wide at one end, and 90' for almost the entire length.
- This spell can cover a square area 460' on a side, with a few left over, if shaped in such a square.
- If you have more cubes than you need, you can either be 'evil' and use them anyway, or be 'good' and push the excess into the air.

Regarding the oddity of the area effect line, this is an instance that proves that the 'many effects or areas are given as cubes' really means 'many' and not 'all', since this effect is obviously not given as cubes.